# Independent watchOS app - Unable to install AppName WatchKit App

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos

Using Xcode 11.3.1, iPhone XR (iOS 13.3.1) and Apple Watch Series 2 (watchOS 6.1.3).

The project is a brand new Independent WatchKit app with SwiftUI.

Runs fine in the simulator, but when I try to run on a physical device I always get this error:

**Unable to install "AppName WatchKit App"**

[image]

Clicking the Details button provides this info:

```
Details

Unable to install "TallyGo WatchKit App"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653057
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402653057
Failure Reason: Device doesn’t support wireless sync.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012370d6e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012370dde9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012374d56a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ab3ec12 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012374d301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001235d5a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ac6fe7a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010ac71552 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63e76583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63e7750e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63e7cace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63e7d452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff63e86a9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff640d16fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff640d0827 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is this related post on the developer forum, but doesn't help. I have connected my iPhone via the USB cable
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/125432

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? My head is about to explode!

Comment: I have seen this type of behaviour before when Xcode is trying to get authorisation on the device, but the device is not ready for it. Have you tried rebooting the watch, iPhone and then restarting Xcode. You may well be asked for your passcode again at which point installation may work.

Comment: This is a really strange error! I've connected my USB cable to my iPhone, launching the independent watch app and I've done it a few times before, so maybe I'll be of help! Just to be sure, you have the Target Memberships checked off properly? Maybe that's preventing the extension from connecting to the app functionality.

Comment: I reported it as a bug in the feedback assistant and provided a sysdiagnose of the Mac, the iPhone and the Watch. Still waiting for answer. With Xcode 11.4.1 I still have the problem.